# kernel types in Raspbian 10 - Buster

Tags: kernel, raspbian-buster

In the `/boot` directory I've found the following kernel files:

- kernel.img: Kernel For ARMv6 - rpi 1 and rpi zero
- kernel7.img: Kernel For ARMv7 - rpi 2 & 3
- kernel7l.img: Used In rpi 4 but I don't know.
- kernel8.img: I don't know.

Does anyone know what kernel7l.img and kernel8.img are used for?

Answer (score 14):

- kernel.img is 32-bit for BCM2835 (RPi1 & Zero)
- kernel7.img is 32-bit for BCM2836 (RPi2) and BCM2837 (RPi3)
- kernel7l.img is 32-bit for BCM2711 (RPi4)
- kernel8.img is 64-bit for BCM2837 (RPi3) or BCM2711 (RPi4)